Unable to re-render newly saved data to a partial view in ASP.NET MVC application
I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application and in html on the click of a button, I call the function shown below - AddGroupFilter.
This passes two fields to the AddGroupFilter controller method and adds it to the database successfully.
The new record I saved exists in the result. Yes I can see it there but it refuses to render on my .cshtml page.
All the previous data is shown, but the new row does not show up.
I am unable to see console.log(data) in my browser. What am I doing wrong here? I think the issue is from the function not being able to render my new data very well.
<div id="GroupFilterTableContainer">
    @if (Model.SearchFilters != null && Model.SearchFilters.Any())
    {
        @Html.Partial("_GroupFiltersTable", Model.SearchFilters)
    }
    else
    {
        <p> No filters found.</p>
    }
</div>

function AddGroupFilter() {
    if ($("#NewSearchFilter_GroupId").val() != "" && $("#NewSearchFilter_TaxId").val() != "") {                
        console.log("firstcall");
        $.post({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddGroupFilter", "Home")',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("secondcall");
                console.log(data);
                ClearNewFilterFields();
                $("#GroupFilterTableContainer").html(data);
                BindFilterTable();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) { {
                console.error("Error:" + error);
                console.error("status:" + status);
                console.error("Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
            } }, 
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("GroupID and TaxID required");
    }
}
        

public ActionResult AddGroupFilter(GroupFilterViewModel ViewModel)
{
    var result = osService.SaveGroupFilters(ViewModel);

    // Ensure result is never null
    if (result == null)
    {
        result = new List<SearchFilter>();
    }

    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_GroupFiltersTable.cshtml", result);
}


What does the html look like on the page? Are the ids the same as you expect in your JS?

The ids are the same .  Looking for a way to show the html

What are you getting in console.log(data); Are you getting the updated html in the console? Any error is coming on the console?

please share the codes for the     var result = osService.SaveGroupFilters(ViewModel); and the _GroupFiltersTable.cshtml partial view codes, your js codes looks good and it should work.

Can you show code from "~/Views/Shared/_GroupFiltersTable.cshtml", and what shows in console.log(data)?
